# IE show me a table with round edges and Edge not

Tags: html

I have created a table with round edges. But it shows round edges in IE but not in Edge.
How can i solve this:

```css
.ms-rteTable-default>tbody>tr>th {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.ms-rteTable-default>tbody>tr>td {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table class="ms-rteTable-default" cellspacing="0" style="width: 50%; height: 1px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ms-rteTableHeaderRow-default">
      <th class="ms-rteTableHeaderEvenCol-default" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100%; height: 1px;">
        <h1>​​​​​</h1>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-default">
      <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="height: 1px;">
        <p>
          <br/>
          <br/>&#160;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Gr. P

Comment: Add your HTML code